# Wrap several elements for accordion in jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, accordion

I currently have the following html:

```
<h3 />
<p />
<p />
<ul />
<ol />

<h3 />
<p />
<p />
<ul />
<ol />

<h3 />
<p />
<p />
<ul />
<ol />
```

I'd like to create an accordion but for this I need the following:

```
<h3 />
<div>
     <p />
     <p />
     <ul />
     <ol />
</div>

<h3 />
<div>
     <p />
     <p />
     <ul />
     <ol />
</div>
```

I have tried the following, but it doesn't work:

```
$('.page2 .articleText p, .page2 .articleText ul').after('<div class="accordion">');
$('.page2 .articleText h4:not(:first)').before('</div>');
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to wrap every group pf `p, p, ul, ol` elements in a separate `<div />` with javascript?

Comment: Why don't you just create the required structure on server side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`.nextUntil()`](http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/) and [`.wrapAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrapAll/) to select and wrap each section, like this:

```
$("h3").each(function() {
    $(this).nextUntil("h3").wrapAll("<div />");
});​
```

[You can see a working demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/yP8ws/)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick'n'dirty solution for wrapping a group of elements into one div:

```
$(function(){
    var h  = $('h3');
    var p1 = $('h3 + p');
    var p2 = $('h3 + p + p');
    var ul = $('h3 + p + p + ul');
    var ol = $('h3 + p + p + ul + ol');

    h.each(function (i) {
        var group = $(p1[i]).add(p2[i]).add(ul[i]).add(ol[i]);
        var div = $('<div />').append(group);
        $(h[i]).after(div);
    });
});
```

I believe if you provided some hooks, the code would be much simpler :)